# Update number of li after removing one of them by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a number of lists and I need to update the total of them after removing one li the code working well but after removing li it's not updated, So how to update the total of li after **removing one**?
I spent a long time to find the solution but I failed!

```js
var totalList = document.getElementById('total');
var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
var allList = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav li");
var removeNotify = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var notifyItem = $(e.delegateTarget).parent();
  var html = $('html');
  html.css('overflowX', 'hidden');
  notifyItem.addClass(notifyItem.data('animation-class'));
  notifyItem.bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    notifyItem.remove();
    html.removeAttr('style');
  }); 
};
$(function() {
  $('.delete').on('click', removeNotify);
  console.log(allList.length - 1);
  
});
// total li
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
$('.delete').on('click', 'li', function(ev){ 
  totalList.innerHTML = allList.length - 1
});
```

```css
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.nav-scroller {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 2.75rem;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.nav-scroller .nav {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.nav-item {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #252629;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: .1s all ease-in-out;
  transition: .1s all ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-nav .title {
  font-family: "Monda-Regular", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
}
.nav-item:hover:not(:first-child){
  background-color: #4362B1;
}
.nav-item:hover p,
.nav-item:hover .date {
  color: #E1E2E2;
}
.nav-item .delete {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #637cbb;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: .1s all ease-in-out;
  transition: .1s all ease-in-out;
}
.nav-item:hover .delete {
  visibility: visible;
}
/*li animation on delete*/
@-webkit-keyframes minimize {
  0% {
    max-height: 10rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
@keyframes minimize {
  0% {
    max-height: 10rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
.navbar-nav li.minimize {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
          animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.navbar-nav li.minimize {
  -webkit-animation-name: minimize;
          animation-name: minimize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="notifyNum align-center d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mr-auto">
          <span id="total" class="fontSize12"></span>
        </div>
<ul id="myList" class="navbar-nav w-100 align-left">
              <li class="nav-item title">
                <h1 class="p-0 m-0 weight700 fontSize20 gray6">Notifications</h1>
              </li>
              <li id="1" class="nav-item" data-animation-class="minimize">
                <h2 class="notifyTitle weight600 fontSize16 gray5 mb-2">test-1 </h2>
                <span class="delete text-center">&times;</span>
              </li>
              <li id="2" class="nav-item" data-animation-class="minimize">
                <h2 class="notifyTitle weight600 fontSize16 gray5 mb-2">test-2 </h2>
                <span class="delete text-center">&times;</span>
              </li>
              <li id="3" class="nav-item" data-animation-class="minimize">
                <h2 class="notifyTitle weight600 fontSize16 gray5 mb-2">test-3 </h2>
                <span class="delete text-center">&times;</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

I need to update the total of lists and display in a div I tried this code but not working

```
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
$('.delete').on('click', 'li', function(ev){ 
  totalList.innerHTML = allList.length - 1
});
```

Comment: Your selectors are backwards. That jQuery is saying .. "look for an `<li>` inside delete class"

Comment: I removed the code out of the function and still not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the `allList` selector within the on click function. The var `allList` doesn't get updated every time you click `delete` with the way you coded it.

Below is a *quick* way to make it work as you'd like.

**change** `totalList.innerHTML = allList.length - 1` to:

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function(ev) {
  totalList.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav li").length - 1
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3r948vok/1/)

Sidenote - you're not excluding the `.title` list element from `allList`. I am not sure whether or not that is intentional, but just noting that `totalList` will **always** show 1, even if you delete all the "test" items...